# Concatenating row values using Inner Join

Tags: sql, join

I have this query that I'm using to join two tables for an update statement. This is the query that I built:

```
DECLARE @DocHoldReasons VARCHAR(8000)
    SET @DocHoldReasons = 'DocType Hold'
    UPDATE dbo.EpnPackages 
    SET Error = 1, Msg =  COALESCE (@DocHoldReasons + ': ', '') + cv.Value  
    FROM EpnPackages p
    INNER JOIN EpnCountyValues cv ON cv.CountyId = p.CountyId and cv.ValueName = 'DocHoldReason'
    WHERE p.Status = 1000
    AND p.Error = 0
```

There are two rows in the EpnCountyValues table with the same ValueName, and I need them both concatenated, and I'm having a tough time doing it. All I can get is the first row value. This is what my resulting string should look like - 'DocType Hold: Test: Test.124.'

eidt: I need the rows with the same ValueName to be concatenated for the update query. There could be more than two rows with ValueName = DocHoldReason

Here's the structure of the EpnCountyValues table:

```
CountyValueId   CountyId   ValueName        Value
      1            1      DocHoldReason      Test
      2            2         xyz             Test1
      3            3      DocHoldReason      Test.124.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want by pre-aggregating the table before the join.  If there are only two values and you don't care about the order, then this will work:

```
DECLARE @DocHoldReasons VARCHAR(8000);
SET @DocHoldReasons = 'DocType Hold';

UPDATE dbo.EpnPackages 
    SET Error = 1,
        Msg = (COALESCE(@DocHoldReasons + ': ', '') + minv +
               (case when minv <> maxv then ': ' + maxv else '' end)
              )
    FROM EpnPackages p INNER JOIN
         (select cv.CountyId, min(cv.value) as minv, max(cv.value) as maxv
          from EpnCountyValues cv
          where cv.ValueName = 'DocHoldReason'
         ) cv
        ON cv.CountyId = p.CountyId
    WHERE p.Status = 1000 AND p.Error = 0;
```

EDIT:

For more than two values, you have to do string concatenation.  That is "unpleasant" in SQL Server.  Here is the approach:

```
DECLARE @DocHoldReasons VARCHAR(8000);
SET @DocHoldReasons = 'DocType Hold';

UPDATE dbo.EpnPackages 
    SET Error = 1,
        Msg = (COALESCE(@DocHoldReasons + ': ', '') + 
               stuff((select ': ' + cv.value
                      from EpnCountyValues cv
                      where cv.ValueName = 'DocHoldReason' and
                            cv.CountyId = p.CountyId
                      for xml path ('')
                     ), 1, 2, '')
               )
    WHERE p.Status = 1000 AND p.Error = 0;
```

This version does it using a correlated subquery rather than a join with an aggregation.

EDIT II:

You can fix this with an additional `coalesce`:

```
DECLARE @DocHoldReasons VARCHAR(8000);
SET @DocHoldReasons = 'DocType Hold';

UPDATE dbo.EpnPackages 
    SET Error = 1,
        Msg = (COALESCE(@DocHoldReasons + ': ', '') + 
               COALESCE(stuff((select ': ' + cv.value
                               from EpnCountyValues cv
                               where cv.ValueName = 'DocHoldReason' and
                                     cv.CountyId = p.CountyId
                               for xml path ('')
                              ), 1, 2, ''), '')
               )
    WHERE p.Status = 1000 AND p.Error = 0;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Your query works like a charm, but the only catch is that, there can be more than two rows with ValuName = DocHoldReason, and I need to concatenate all the rows. Is there another way to loop through all the ValueNames with DocHoldReason? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Gordon, Is there any way to just set the Msg as only 'DocType Hold' if there are no values in the EpnCountyValues table for ValueName = DocHoldReason. Right now, it works fine as long as there are rows in the EpnCountyValues table. If there are no rows, then Msg column is NULL, but I want it to be 'DocType Hold'. I'm scratching my head here. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! You saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the EpnCountyValues table twice!

Something like this,

```
DECLARE @DocHoldReasons VARCHAR(8000)
SET @DocHoldReasons = 'DocType Hold'

Select @DocHoldReasons + ': ' + ev1.Value + ': ' + ev2.Value 
From EpnPackages p
Join EpnCountyValues ev1 on p.packageID = ev1.packageID 
Join EpnCountyValues ev2 on ev1.ValueName = ev2.ValueName 
Where ev1.ValueName = 'DocHoldRegion'
And p.status = 1000
And p.error = 0
```

Does that select look right to you? If so, run the update. I always try to run a select before an update. I have to admit, I'm a bit confused why you're joining on CountyID, but then it seems like you'll be updating the values from different counties?